# how do I fix withr error and install ggplot2 package?

Tags: r, ggplot2, quick-install-package

I am new in R language and I want to install package "ggplot2"
but during installation this warning happens that says :

```
    Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ggplot2’:
 .  onAttach failed in attachNamespace() for 'ggplot2', details:
    call: loadNamespace(x)
    error: there is no package called ‘withr’
```

I've also tried :

```
    remove.packages(c("ggplot2", "data.table"))
    install.packages('Rcpp', dependencies = TRUE)
    install.packages('ggplot2', dependencies = TRUE)
    install.packages('data.table', dependencies = TRUE)
```

after installation ggplot2 a warning says:

```
    Warning messages:
    1: In install.packages("ggplot2", dependencies = TRUE) :
    installation of package ‘DBI’ had non-zero exit status
    2: In install.packages("ggplot2", dependencies = TRUE) :
    installation of package ‘withr’ had non-zero exit status
    3: In install.packages("ggplot2", dependencies = TRUE) :
    installation of package ‘pkgload’ had non-zero exit status
```

But if I just write this code:

```
 install.packages("ggplot2")
```

in the next line says :

```
 also installing the dependency ‘withr’
```

and after installation it says:

```
     install.packages("ggplot2") :
     installation of package ‘withr’ had non-zero exit status
```

I've also install Rtools
I am using Rstudio.
thank you.

I want to use ggplot without any error
I am using R 4.3.2

Comment: There are almost certainly warnings or errors associated with why `withr` does not install correctly, without which there is very little we can say with confidence. Please try _just_ `install.packages("withr")`, then [edit] your question and paste all of the console output between the `install.packages(.)` call and the last error message into a [code block] in your question. Thanks!